# I am need assistance with the next steps in Java loop

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

I am working to create a program in JOptionPane where the computer guesses the users number from 0-999 then with interaction with the user, finally guesses the number (or identifies the user is cheating) then outputs a congratulations screen with the amount of guesses it took and a message.

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GuessMyNumber
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Prepare
        Object[] options1 = { "Yes", "No",
                "I'm Thinking" };

        JPanel Name = new JPanel();
        Name.add(new JLabel("Do you want to play a game? \n"+"\n Please         Enter Your Name"));
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
        Name.add(textField);

        int person = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, Name, null,
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                null, options1, null);
        if (person == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Awesome! Nice to meet    you,"+textField.getText()+",Select 'OK' so I can tell you the rules");
            }
    if (person == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ok dude, take it easy! I was just asking, geez");
    }
    if (person == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hey dude, we do not have all day... HURRY UP");
    }

    //Instructions
    else if (person==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "OK  "+textField.getText()+ "\nThe name of the game is for me to guess your number.\n"+"First and foremost, I need you to think of a number from 0 to 999.\n"+"I will then provide you with a number, you need to tell me if I am too LOW or too HIGH, or if I am RIGHT and guessed correctly.\n"+"Are you ready?  If so, make sure you remember your number!", "RULES", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }

    //Game Start
     Object[] options2 = { "Too LOW", "Too HIGH",
            "You Are CORRECT" };

    int result = ((999+0)/2);
    int g1=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Is your number   "+result+"?", null,
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
            null, options2, null);
    //Guess 1 Low
    if (g1==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
    {
        int ga = ((999+result)/2);

        int g1a=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Is your number   "+ga+"?", null,
                                JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
            null, options2, null);


    }
    //Guess 1 High
    else if (g1==JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
    {
        int gb =((result+0)/2);

        int g1b=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Is your number   "+gb+"?", null,
                                JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
            null, options2, null);

    }

    else if (g1==JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Awesome "+textField.getText()+ ", this was fun!\n"+"For a second there I really thought you had me stumped!\n"+"If you would like to play again, please restart the program.\n"+"Thank you for Playing!", " I GUESSED YOUR NUMBER!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    //Guess 2


    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @MarounMaroun OP wants us to write the high-low game loop

Comment: next step...or rather, How to implement for loop for this to guess the High and Low as well as count the number of guesses made